# Doctrine deadlock with ORM updates

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out what is causing deadlocks in my Symfony 2 application. I'm running a cronjob that does batch-updates on a fairly large dataset and one part of it causes this error:

> Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing
>   'UPDATE SpotEvent SET ts = ?, current = ? WHERE id = ?' with params
>   ["2015-12-28 00:35:27", 1, 39316]:  SQLSTATE[40P01]: Deadlock
>   detected: 7 ERROR:  deadlock detected DETAIL:  Process 32030 waits for
>   ShareLock on transaction 2130787; blocked by process 32029. Process
>   32029 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2130786; blocked by process
>   32030. HINT:  See server log for query details. CONTEXT:  while updating tuple (105,68) in relation "spotevent" (uncaught exception)
>   at
>   /home/maf/symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php
>   line 91 while running console command

The code causing it is basically this:

```
check event
if (already in database) {
    update timestamp
} else {
    create new
}
```

From what I see in the error, the first branch causes the deadlock, but from what I read about deadlocks, the second should be more likely. In any case I don't understand why I have a deadlock at all.

I should say I am running this job in 6 parallel processes. However, there is no overlap between them (i.e. job one is checking from 1-200, job 2 from 201 to 400, etc.)

I'm using PostgreSQL as the database backend. My "check event" step is done using DQL, everything else is pure ORM.

Comment: When using the ORM to fetch data, there might be things happening in the background which you did not expected. I would have a look at the log which queries are actually executed to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I checked the log and it contains no helpful information. It especially doesn't show any other queries.

Comment: I've removed the update and instead delete the event, and create a new one in both cases, and that resolves the deadlock, so the deadlock definitely is from the update branch. I still don't understand how.